# http_build_query() without url encoding

Tags: php, urlencode

Is there a way to use `http_build_query()` without having it URL encode according to some RFC standard?

Why I don't want to URL encode everything: I'm querying the Ebay API.. They honestly insist on parameter names not being URL encoded, as far as commas in parentheses.  E.g. DomainName(0) is a parameter, and the query fails if those parens are encoded.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function on a result string which you get from `http_build_query()`

Comment: You could create your own function for it, `http_build_query_decoded()`. You would have to copy the parameters, though, since you need to pass them to `http_build_query`.

Comment: This problem no longer exists in PHP 5.4 and above, the ampersand does not get url encoded.

Comment: @BasilMusa The keys and values still get url encoded. This solution decodes those too.

Answer (score 8):

**PHP 5.3.1 (Buggy Behavior)**
http_build_query **DOES** escape the '&' ampersand character that joins the parameters. Example: `user_id=1&amp;setting_id=2`.

**PHP 5.4+**
http_build_query **DOES NOT** escape the '&' ampersand character that joins the parameters. Example: `user_id=1&setting_id=2`

Example:

```
$params = array(
    'user_id' => '1', 
    'setting_id' => '2'
);
echo http_build_query($params);

// Output for PHP 5.3.1:
user_id=1&amp;setting_id=2   // NOTICE THAT: '&' character is escaped

// Output for PHP 5.4.0+:
user_id=1&setting_id=2       // NOTICE THAT: '&' character is NOT escaped
```

#### Solution when targeting multiple version

**Option #1:** Write a wrapper function:

```
/** 
 * This will work consistently and will never escape the '&' character
 */
function buildQuery($params) {
    return http_build_query($params, '', '&');
}
```

**Option #2:** Ditch the http_build_query function and write your own.

Comment: How about the php.ini core setting arg_separator.output [link](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.output)? I'm using PHP 5.4.34, and it has the output separator set to &amp; while the input separator is &. Seems very strange to me.

Comment: @sootsnoot a bit late but for anyone reading your question: "arg_separator: arg_separator.output is used to separate arguments but may be overridden by specifying this parameter."

Answer (score 6):

Nope, it appears to always want to encode (which it should, it is meant to URL encode when building a list of params for a URL).

You could make your own...

```
$params = array('a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B');

$paramsJoined = array();

foreach($params as $param => $value) {
   $paramsJoined[] = "$param=$value";
}

$query = implode('&', $paramsJoined);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Sqyxm1).

Comment: this one will not handle nested arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try their JSON API instead. I tried to get a working sample, but I don't have an app name so I can't verify the result. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$appName = "Your App Name Here";

$post_data = array(
  'jsonns.xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
  'jsonns.xs' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
  'jsonns.tns' => 'http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services',
  'tns.findItemsByKeywordsRequest' => array(
    'keywords' => 'harry potter pheonix'
  )
);

$headers = array(
  "X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON", 
  "X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
  "X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME: findItemsByKeywords",
  "X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME: $appName"
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result) {
  $response = json_decode($result);
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

You'll need to to fill `$appName` with whatever the name of the app is. Also the `X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME` will need to be set to the actual call, and the JSON modified if the call is different.

Answer (score 4):

http_build_query() is INVALID without urlencoding. Maybe you accidentally double-encode it?
For example, try to build http query for this array:

```
$params = array('a' => 'a&b=b');
```

Without encoding, you would get

```
a=a&b=b
```

When properly encoded, you would get

```
a=a%26b%3Db
```

which is correct. If you skip encoding, be sure to avoid URL injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).
Or use http_build_query with the *$arg_separator* argument.

```
$query_data= $data = array('bar', 'baz'=>'boom');
$numeric_prefix= 'test_';
$arg_separator = '&';
$http_query = http_build_query ( $query_data, $numeric_prefix, $arg_separator );
var_dump( $http_query );
```

the output of the above is

```
string 'test_0=bar&baz=boom' (length=19)
```

*numeric_prefix*: if the array indexes are numbers, this string is added as prefix in each index. In this case the '*test_0=bar'*.

*arg_separator* : is used to separate arguments. If non is given php use the *arg_separator.output* difined in php.ini

See [php http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to create a GET string to attach it to the end of a url like this -

```
$get_params = array(
    'include' => array(
        'enrollments',
        'current_grading_period_scores'
    ),
    'enrollment_type' => array(
        'student',
    ),

);
$get_params = http_build_query($get_params);
$get_params = urldecode($get_params);
$url = $domain.$slug;
$url = $url.'?'.$get_params;
echo $url;
```

which prints out

```
include[0]=enrollments&include[1]=current_grading_period_scores&enrollment_type[0]=student
```

But my api didn't like the numbers in the square brackets, so I found a regular expression that removes the numbers -

```
preg_replace('/[[0-9]+]/', '[]', $get_params);
```

The final code, and the result -

```
$get_params = array(
    'include' => array(
        'enrollments',
        'current_grading_period_scores'
    ),
    'enrollment_type' => array(
        'student',
    ),

);
$get_params = http_build_query($get_params);
$get_params = urldecode($get_params);
$get_params = preg_replace('/[[0-9]+]/', '[]', $get_params);
$url = $domain.$slug;
$url = $url.'?'.$get_params;
echo $url;
```

Prints out -

`include[]=enrollments&include[]=current_grading_period_scores&enrollment_type[]=student`

If someone knows of a better regex let me know, I'm kind of a noob with it.

Answer (score 0):

my take on alex's answer but is faster

```
$params = array('a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B');
$query = '';

foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
   $query .= $param.'='.$value .'&';
}

echo substr($query, 0, -1);
```

Comment: You can use the second parameter of `trim()` also to specify characters to be trimmed. E.g. I would use `trim($query, '&')` instead of `substr($query, 0, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This could also work

```
$fields = array(
    'a' => 'A', 
    'b' => 'B'
 );

$separator = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $fields_string .= $separator . $key . '=' . $value; 
    $separator = '&'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried do this recently https://gist.github.com/marcocesarato/4293986fe93139f04d8269aa3fbd47e9 the difference is that this function is array recursive and compatible with PHP4. You can manage here the urlencode

```
<?php
/**
 * Build URL query params
 * as http_build_query build a query url the difference is 
 * that this function is array recursive and compatible with PHP4
 *
 * @author Marco Cesarato <cesarato.developer@gmail.com>
 * @param $query
 * @param string $parent
 * @return string
 *
 * @example
 * $p = array('abbreviations' => array('google' => 'ggle', 'facebook' => array('abb_key' => 'fbook', 'fcbk')), 'key' => 'value');
 * echo url_build_query($p);
 */
function url_build_query($query, $parent = null){
    $query_array = array();
    foreach($query as $key => $value){
        $_key = empty($parent) ?  urlencode($key) : $parent . '[' . urlencode($key) . ']';
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $query_array[] = url_build_query($value, $_key);
        } else {
            $query_array[] = $_key . '=' . urlencode($value);
        }
    }
    return implode('&', $query_array);
}
```