# Creating a URL (HTTP Query) with PHP without escaping special charaters

Tags: php, url

I want this:

```
datasetid=GHCND&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2010-05-01&enddate=2010-05-01
```

I have this:

```
$data=['datasetid'=>'GHCND','locationid'=>'ZIP:28801','startdate'=>'2010-05-01','enddate'=>'2010-05-01'];
```

I tried this:

```
exit(http_build_query($data));
```

I got this:

```
datasetid=GHCND&locationid=ZIP%3A28801&startdate=2010-05-01&enddate=2010-05-01
```

How can I prevent `ZIP:28801` from being escaped as `ZIP%3A28801`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132721/http-build-query-without-url-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [urldecode](http://de.php.net/urldecode) the string like this:

`urldecode(http_build_query($data));`