# http_build_query not correctly encoding my post fields

Tags: php

It's a strange issue I'm facing. Here is the CURL request I'm sending:

```
    $fields = array(
        'action' => 'json',
        'region' => '',
        'states' => array('TX'),
        'start' => '4/2/2010',
        'end' => '4/2/2017',
        'internalcomments' => 'no'
    );
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    $jsonResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

However, when I'm printing out the content of the `$fields_string`, I see a trademark icon in the query string:

`action=json®ion=&states%5B0%5D=AL&states%5B1%5D=TX&start=04%2F01%2F2010&end=04%2F07%2F2017&internalcomments=no`

Notice the ® icon after the word json? Any idea where that's coming from?

Comment: Its `print '&reg'`; do `print $fields_string = htmlentities(http_build_query($fields));` to see the real content. Query is ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132721/http-build-query-without-url-encoding#8616340

Comment: It is typical for the html world a browser ignores the missing `;` at the end and evaluates what he can. Test: `print 'x&nbspx';` becomes `x x` , but full right syntax is `print 'x&nbsp;x';`