# Avoiding the conversion of HTML entities in http_build_query in php

Tags: php, html, url, html-entities

Prevent conversion of HTML entities.

Please look at the code below:

```
$array = array(
  "id" => 123456,
  "currency" => "EUR",
);

var_dump(http_build_query($array));

//OUTPUT:
string 'id=123456&currency=EUR' (length=22)
```

Ok that works. But some servers give me this output:

```
string(25) "pspid=123456¤cy=EUR"
```

So, some servers treat `&curren` as an HTML entity. But I don't want that.

How can I avoid the unwanted conversion of HTML Entities?

Comment: This is just output. If you pass this url to server - everything will be okay

Comment: What php version are you using? There are a few differences on how http_build_query works in different php versions

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, but why is `&curren` converted to Entities and on other servers it is not converted?

Comment: @lloiacono php 5.3.10 ... not the most recent version lol

Comment: @Julian Have a look on this https://eval.in/803318

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. 
Just use `htmlentities` on the output.

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$array = array(
  "id" => 123456,
  "currency" => "EUR",
);
print_r(http_build_query($array));
echo PHP_EOL;
print_r(htmlentities(http_build_query($array)));

//OUTPUT:
id=123456&currency=EUR
id=123456&amp;currency=EUR
```

Link:
https://eval.in/803318

Answer (score 0):

Check your php version since:

PHP 5.3.1 (Buggy Behavior) http_build_query DOES escape the '&' ampersand character that joins the parameters. Example: user_id=1&setting_id=2.

PHP 5.4+ http_build_query DOES NOT escape the '&' ampersand character that joins the parameters. Example: user_id=1&setting_id=2

For more details check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317655/1016425