# Laravel the second parameter of the passed URL is not shown while sharing with social media

Tags: laravel, web, model-view-controller

I'm using https://github.com/jorenvh/laravel-share for a Laravel project. It works well except it doesn't work while adding multiple parameters to the URL which is going to be shared.

```
 public function ShareWidget(Request $request)
{

    $shareURL =  url('/') . '/newproducts' . '?' . http_build_query([
        'catalog' => $request->catalog,
        'category' => $request->category
    ]);


    $shareComponent = ShareFacade::page(
        $shareURL,
        null,
    )
        ->facebook()
        ->telegram()
        ->whatsapp();
    return view('share-component', compact('shareComponent'));
}
```

The ShareWidget function is responsible to make a URL and share it with the users on social medias. While I print out the ShareURL it shows what's supposed to be: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/newproducts?catalog=1&category=11`.

However, when its comes to  the final stage which is the link that had been shared with users on social medias it misses the second parameter. No matter what it is. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/newproducts?catalog=1`.

As you see **&category=11** part is missed in the second one.

Comment: you need to properly encode the ``$shareURL`` before passing to the ``page`` method. When you're sharing the url (e.g.)  ``http://127.0.0.1:8000/newproducts?catalog=1&category=11`` and when rendered, it outputs as ``https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://127.0.0.1:8000/newproducts?catalog=1&category=11`` & when  user clicks on the link, it'll open FB and FB will only read ``http://127.0.0.1:8000/newproducts?catalog=1`` as the value of ``u`` parameter since the other param's are not encoded and will act as another parameter for the URL causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the **URL** before before assigning to `$shareComponent`

```
$shareURL =  url('/') . '/newproducts' . '?' . http_build_query([
    'catalog' => $request->catalog,
    'category' => $request->category
]);

$shareURL = urlencode($shareURL);
```

for more details, [read this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132721/http-build-query-without-url-encoding)

Comment: It solved the issue. Now it's working like a charm. I couldn't find to encode URL anywhere. I wonder why it happens?

Comment: You are welcome, the problem is with & symbol which `http_build_query` escape this character which joins the parameters so you need to encode it before sending.

Comment: This is a duplicate question and should have been marked duplicate instead of answering with duplicate answer. 